# For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only son, that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life

Tags: sentence-meaning, conjunctions, adverbial-phrases

> For God so loved the world that he gave his one and only son, that
>   whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

1.Is 'For' used as a conjunction?

2.What is the subject in the sentence?

> that whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life.

3.Is this part of sentence used as an adverbial-that-clause? I think this clause functions as in

> I eat that I may live.

Comment: The subject of  **gave**  is **He**, which was omitted from your transcription.  The subject of **loved** is **God**. The subject of  **shall not perish** is  **whoever believes in Him**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo it's my mistake. It was omitted.

Comment: Your understanding of **that** in *that whoever...* is correct: it has the force of **so that**.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct in assuming that **for** is used as a conjunction there (see definition #2 in [**the Merriam-Webster dictionary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for)). More generally, it is just an old-fashioned way to say **because**. You would see it used like that a lot if you ever get a chance to read the King James version of the Bible or Shakespeare's plays. So, we can actually reword the sentence to make it read like this:

> **Because** God so loved the world that he gave his one and only son...

In other words, it's saying that the reason God gave his one and only son is because he loved the world very much.

2. The subject of the clause **whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life** is **whoever believes in him**. Why? Well, in simple language, the subject of a sentence or a clause is what we're talking about and the predicate is what it's doing. What or who are we talking about in this clause? Apparently, it's **whoever believes in him**. That's what makes it the subject. What is happening with them or what are they doing? They **shall not perish but have eternal life**. And that's your predicate.
3. That's exactly right. **that** connects the two dependent clauses **he gave his one and only son** and **whoever believes in him shall not perish but have eternal life**. And as Tᴚoɯɐuo aptly pointed out, it's similar in meaning to the expression **so that**.

Comment: If you find the use of *for* in the sense of “because” to be “old-fashioned” then (1) you'd be (mostly:-) right and (2) there’s a lot more where that came from, for the familiar King James Version of that verse is even fancier still: ***“For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.”*** This may be hard for learners to understand in the old style it's written in, and might give even native speakers pause.